# Playing Youtube Video in WebView without share option?

Tags: android, android-webview, android-videoview, android-youtube-api

I want to play multiple youtube video in single page, Youtube API not supporting this feature. So i decided to use WebView, but issue is that sometimes WebView showing comment, and share option showing other pages. How can i avoid this ? Can i use VideoView for this purpose ?

Answer (score 0):

The Google Developer's channel on Youtube has an [example](http://www.youtube.com/watch?list=PLhBgTdAWkxeDcgr7lljcTt1bKaHY48Toi&v=fhWaJi1Hsfo) of something like this. There is an example [here](http://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/#How_It_Works) called "Video Wall".